# Compiler thinks struct is pointer to struct

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I declare an array of structs and want to declare a second into which I can make a copy in order to re-initialze the structure at the start of each unit test.

So, I declare in 2 header files

```
extern peripheralsArray_t Peripherals;  
extern peripheralsArray_t DefaultPeripherals;
```

and in 2 c files

```
peripheralsArray_t Peripherals =
{... init  values };
peripheralsArray_t DefaultPeripherals;
```

BUT, when I try to assign `DefaultPeripherals = Peripherals;`  the GCC comiler (under Cygwin) says

```
error: incompatible types when assigning 
       to type ‘peripheralsArray_t’ from type ‘struct _peripherals *’
```

Why does it think that `Peripherals` is a pointer?

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else. Where is _peripherals coming from?

Comment: You might get better answers if you exhibited the definition of `peripheralsArray_t`.

Comment: How can it matter what the difinition of peripheralsArray is if it is used consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your type names are descriptive and `peripheralsArray_t` really is an *array*.

C does not support array assignment, which is what you are trying to do.

So the compiler see a array in a RHS context and deduces that it should decay to a pointer, which then has the wrong type.

Comment: +1 yes, it is an array. Ok, I'll assign element by element, or use memcpy() (there is no "deep copying" needed. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to an array.  I'm assuming that `peripheralsArray_t` is a typedef'd array (which is almost always a bad idea as well).

Comment: Just curious, why is a typedef array A Bad Thing?

Comment: @Mawg:  Because 1) `typedef`s are meant to be used for types that will change due to some environment condition, not just to hide the type of another type, and 2) your array type is not opaque.  `typedef`'ing a pointer (array) can be ok if it is essentially a black box, but yours is not and it just makes the code harder to understand.